# Remote access of network computer

Tags: apache

I am not sure how or if this can be done.  I have a home network and would like to see a computer,not the server, via a remote location.  I have Apache on my server.  Example: the network computers I would like to see ip 152.254.1.33.  Is there a way to add this ip to Apache root directory?  I have tried to add a shortcut with in the root directory and it only works on the home network, will not via remote connection.

Answer (score 1):

I need some clarification here on what you are trying to acomplish, are you trying to access the Apache website outside of the local network?
If that is the case, Apache is automatically set to listen on all network interfaces, you can check this in your virtual host configuration in the sites-enabled directory of your apache installation.
You should see something like  in the 000-default.conf

You can test if apache is serving pages up correctly using the command

> curl 127.0.0.1

You should see the HTML of the page being served.

If this is the case, then it's likely the firewall on your machine/router or your ISP is blocking the required ports. You can allow Apache through the firewall on Ubuntu using sudo ufw allow Apache Full

If you give me some more info in comments we can probably work this out.

Comment: I have a server with apache, I have computer 2 on the network.  I want to be able to connect to computer 2 when I am not at home via my network.  I would like to know if it is possible to do with Apache?   I thought it would work if I created a shortcut with in the Apache htdoc folder.  It would not work, when you go to the folder via the internet, it list the shortcut as a file that you can not open.

Comment: No, Apache is a webserver it can only serve web content, if you wish, to connect remotely to a computer to control it's movements, access it's GUI etc. You need to use remote desktop software such as VNC, SPICE, TeamViewer etc. At least that's what I think you are asking?